Payment Gateway redirect/iframe to/from payment provider
I'm developing a payment gateway extension and it "works" in the sense of I can show it in the backend and frontend and have my "Place Order" button.
But that's where I despair..
I want to:

Via API Call, create an order at the external  payment gateway backend (I can do that with curl in the Gateway Client
When I receive the order URL from the external payment gateway, I want to redirect to this URL so that the customer can pay there. Alternatively, display the URL in an iframe so that the customer can pay.

How can I do step 2? I can't find that out.. Both options would be ok for me..
Thanks a lot in advance!

I solved the problem myself now.
Basically the solution I was looking for is like this:

In frontend/web/template/payment/form.html, I do set my JS action.
 <div class="actions-toolbar">
         <div class="primary">
             <button data-role="review-save"
                     class="action primary checkout"
                     type="submit"
                     data-bind="
                         click: talerAction,
                         attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                         enable: (getCode() == isChecked()),
                         css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()}                                "
                     disabled>
                 <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
             </button>
         </div>
     </div>


In the JS, I do open my payment popup

At the end of the JS, i simply put this.placeOrder() and it goes on with the normal payment flow.



There would be 2 options.

Iframe - The payment form would be displayed in the Checkout screen itself. You need to follow the instructions regarding the parameters to be passed in the Payment Gateway. (cancel_url, return_url, etc.).
As per the URL param given, create controllers and get the orders created programmatically.

Redirection - Same as iframe form, pass the params with the custom route link, and upon the payment response, create the orders using Rest API.


"When I receive the order URL from the external payment gateway, I want to redirect to this URL so that the customer can pay there. Alternatively, display the URL in an iframe so that the customer can pay."
-- Usually, the payment gateway has the documentation - link, and params to pass. Please let me know the Payment Gateway you are trying to integrate.

Basically I would love to create something similar to PayPal. Where I will click on Button Place Order and then create it on the backend. Then it opens the popup where I can pay and if the payment is successful, it will redirect to the success page. The Payment Gateway I'm trying to integrate is GNU Taler. A new payment gateway currently in development.

@kAYd9iN, good to hear that you have done it. Just a suggestion from my end.

Create an order with pending status on clicking a button (pass controller route URL as a return URL)
We will get payment status-related data in the controller.
If it succeeds, update the order with the status and create an invoice based on the method selected - authorize, authorize & capture.
If it fails, cancel the order.

